# How to output text in ukrainian language in r markdown

Tags: r, rmarkdown

I want to write book and I need outputing text ib ukrainian language (forma pdf). I don`t understand how to do it. I tryed using "babel" but it didn`t work.
[image]

[image]

Comment: `\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}\usepackage[ukrainian]{babel}`  should work but the error means you have not installed ukrainian support,  for vanilla texlive that would be `tlmgr install babel-ukrainian`  in linux texlive or miktex, something similar

Comment: welcome to tex,sx.  There definitely does exist a Ukrainian package for babel, so I expect that it just isn't installed on your system.

Answer (score 1):

This document in Quarto markdown format (save it with extension `.qmd`, not `.Rmd`) and the default xelatex engine do no set `\usepackage[ukrainian]{babel}` but internally `\usepackage[bidi=default]{babel}`.

However, setting `lang: ua` seems enough, as the latex output take care of define or redefine the names as `\contentsname`, `\listfigurename`, etc.

Note 1: Quarto by default use the KOMA classes but if you change `article` to  `scrartcl` you will realize that the output is not correct. If you will  need this classes, you should explore another way (i.e., a custom template to avoid the mistakes, and at the same time take advantage of this to avoid any  header includes).

Note 2: Not less important, you should use a font with all appropriated glyphs, I don't know if the ones I've tried (DejaVu, Symbola) are good enough.

[image: MWE]

```
---
title: "Моя книга українською"
author: "Александр Минаев"
format: pdf
toc: true
lof: true
mainfont: DejaVu Serif # font with UA glyphs
lang: ua
keep-tex: true
documentclass: article # Do not use KOMA
---

## вступ

Це мій гарний текст українською. 

![Мій приклад фігури](example-image){#fig-ex width="10%" fig-pos="h"}

# Прощання

Хай живе Україна
```